# What method is called during Ilogger conversion of structured logging arguments to string?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, ilogger, structured-logging

I have an object that I want to pass to logging (default built-in logging to console, no libraries used) as argument like this:

```
logger.LogDebug("Executing MongoDB command: {Command}", command);
```

What I was expecting is that the result will be a call to `command.ToString()`, but the result of this call differs from the actual `ToString()` call.

P.S. The object in question is `BsonDocument` from MongoDB drivers if this has any importance.

P.P.S. I have compared to the interpolated string result as well and it is different (it seems it returns `ToString()` as I expected):

```
logger.LogDebug($"Executing MongoDB command: {command}");
```

Comment: This isn't an interpolated string; those start with `$`. Logger message templates play by their own rules. The MSDN has a [neat little article](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/loggermessage) (maybe slightly out of date by now, but I expect the basics still apply).

Comment: I pretty much sure that you are looking for "structured logging", not string interpolation.

Comment: I guess I mixed it up with the new C# 10 feature that allows for the interpolated strings to actually do the same (structured logging). I have updated the question

Comment: It depends on the logging provider. Which one are you using (serilog, nlog, ecc.). Eg. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

Comment: It is just a built-in provider so far writing to the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default formatter will format an **IEnumerable** object into a comma separated string, you can find the source code here:

https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LogValuesFormatter.cs,229

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer, that seems to be the case! It is a `ToString()` after all, just on the elements